# Represent Number in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know if there are any build-in class of python3 that can represent the number in all **hex**, **binary**, **integer**. type.

So I do not need to implment lots of methods to convert from one form to the another.

For example

```
number = SomeClass(number,base)
# then I can call the build in function hex(), int(), bin() to convert the number
"0b0000" = bin(number)
"0x0000" = hex(number)
 "0" = int(number)
```

Comment: This is not valid Python code.

Comment: `int` does the opposite of what you showed in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)(object=''). In particular you can use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)

Just simply call .format() function and pass in the value. For example:

```
number = 5435
print('bin: {0:b}   hex: {0:x}   int: {0:d}'.format(number))
```

output:
`bin: 1010100111011   hex: 153b   int: 5435`

or

```
number = 5435
print('bin: {0:#b}   hex: {0:#x}   int: {0:d}'.format(number))
```

output:
`bin: 0b1010100111011   hex: 0x153b   int: 5435`

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with the built-in integers and functions:

```py
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 10 2019, 23:51:51) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181127] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> i = 5
>>> bin(i)
'0b101'
>>> hex(i)
'0x5'
>>> i
5
```

If you want to obtain a string representation of `i`, you can use `str(i)`.

To obtain the number itself from other bases: `i = int("ff", 16)`.